# Почему await con.commit() вызывает ошибку ValueError?

Tags: python, mysql, aiogram

Aiomysql использую в связке с Aiogram. Эксперементальным путём выяснил, что строка await con.commit() вызывает ошибку приведённую в конце. Но почему?

```
async def __query(self, *args, **kwargs):
    con = await aiomysql.connect(
            host=self.__db_host,
            user=self.__db_login,
            password=self.__db_pass,
            db=self.__db_name,
    )
    cur = await con.cursor()
    await cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
    res = await cur.fetchall()
    await con.commit()
    await cur.close()
```

Ошибка что возникает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iindin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
GeneratorExit

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iindin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 273, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "/home/iindin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 127, in notify
    current_handler.reset(ctx_token)
ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='current_handler' at 0x7f7ab7a7df90> at 0x7f7ab5caa800> was created in a different Context
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Handler.notify at 0x7f7ab5c42140>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iindin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 127, in notify
    current_handler.reset(ctx_token)
ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='current_handler' at 0x7f7ab7a7df90> at 0x7f7ab5c7bc40> was created in a different Context
    return res
```

Comment: А вы там что-то записываете, что вам нужен `commit`? И мне кажется надо в обратном порядке делать - сначала курсор закрыть, хотя я не уверен.

Comment: @CrazyElf И читаю и записываю. Изначально использовал, pymysql. После портирования на aiomysql начала появляться эта ошибка.